# Running macros on Hidden Sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have a main sheet called "JE". This sheet is the main form of my workbook. There are many sheets that are called and referenced in macros. I would like to hide all of these sheets so **just** the main form/sheet appears. But, for example, on the main sheet I have a button that, once clicked, triggers a macro which takes the user to a separate sheet of listed values. On the main form/sheet, I have written a sub to hide all of the sheets but once I saved the code, it didn't hide all of the sheets. I've seen other questions that are somewhat similar to mine but, I've never had to do something like this before and I'm unsure of how to incorporate those answers to my workbook, if I even can.

I also tried to write some code to unhide the sheets the macros are touching but that hasn't worked so far.

Here is the sub I tried implementing on the main sheet:

```
Sub HideSheets()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
If ws.Name <> "JE" Then
    ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Here is the code I tried adding to the macro that is connected to the button I mentioned earlier:

```
   Sub acct_search()
'
' acct_search Macro
'

'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("acct_codes").Visible = True

    Sheets("acct_codes").Select


End Sub
```

it works as it normally should but doesn't stay hidden. I'd like it to only be visible when called upon by that macro and once the user leaves the sheet that has all of the accounts, I'd like the sheet to go back to being hidden.

Could I write a sub in each sheet I want to hide that looks something like:

```
Sub HideSheet()

    Dim sheet As Worksheet

    Set sheet = ActiveSheet 'Or set sheet = SheetName

    sheet.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

End Sub
```

Comment: Your `acct_search` macro unhides, then hides the same sheet. Don't you just need to comment out/remove `Sheets("acct_codes").Visible = False`?

Comment: In `HideSheets` you should use `ThisWorkbook` instead of `ActiveWorkbook`  In `acct_search` your code doesn't pause once you activate the *acct_codes* sheet, so as @BruceWayne suggests, remove the last two lines where you re-hide that sheet.

Comment: @BruceWayne That allowed me to navigate to the hidden sheet, yes, but on the sheet "acct_codes" there is a button that takes the user back to the main sheet but once I return to the main form/main sheet, the sheet "acct_codes" becomes unhidden and visible again. I'd like it to only be visible when called upon by that button/macro and that's it.

Comment: What's the code that takes you to the Main Sheet? Is it a link, or a macro?  Is that the `HideSheets()` macro?  You should maybe also change the `IF` statement to `If ws.Name <> "JE" or ws.Name = "acct_codes" Then ...`

Comment: @BruceWayne it is a macro. There is a button titled "Journal" and once clicked it just navigates back to the main sheet.  The code for that macro is just: `Sub Back_to_JE()
'
' Back_to_JE Macro
'

'
    Sheets("JE").Select
End Sub
`

Comment: @BruceWayne I'd like to avoid hard coding sheet names because I have about 21 other sheets I'd like to hide.

Comment: The acct_code sheet has a BeforeDoubleClick sub and when I double click a code on that sheet, the acct_code sheet goes back to being hidden. But when I use the `Journal` button which takes the user back to the main sheet, it **does not** remain hidden

Comment: You can call `HideSheets` from the `Worksheet_Activate` event of your main sheet: whenever you return to that sheet any other sheets will be hidden.

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys. I've gotten it to work. I appreciate the help.